# Least-squares Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression, projection-matrices

1. In least-squares, say we have $n$-points in 2-D space. Now, assume these points don't lie on a line(2-D hyperplane). Do we find $n$-dimensional hyperplane on which all these points lie?
2. If yes, then say I want a line(2-D hyperplane) which is a
   least-squares approximation for the $n$ points. Is that 2-D hyperplane a projection of the n-dimensional hyperplane we found earlier.

**EDIT:**
New Questions after reading the answer.

Say, after solving I obtained the b and m. 
Questions:

1. What the following vector subspace represent? 
   $$m \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots\\ x_n \end{bmatrix} +b\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{bmatrix}$$
2. How the does the line in $R^2$ ,i.e.,  $y=mx+b$, relate to above columnspace?

Comment: Your question is confusing. When you say $n$-points, do you mean points in $n$-space, or do you mean $n$ points in the plane? If you have points in $n$-space, how many do you have? Far more than $n$? You have to decide what you're trying to model here. You can do all sorts of least-squares fits of data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to do *linear* regression for $n$ points in $\Bbb R^2$, you are seeking a line of the form $y=mx+b$ that is the "best fit." This is often set up as a standard calculus question, minimizing the square-error. As a linear algebra problem, you consider the system of linear equations $mx_i + b = y_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$, and set this up as a matrix problem:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 1 \\ x_2 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ x_n & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} m \\ b \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{bmatrix}, \quad A\mathbf x = \mathbf y, \text{ for short}.$$
Assuming the $n$ data points do not lie on a line, this linear system is inconsistent. We find the least squares solution by projecting the vector $\mathbf y$ onto the column space (image) of $A$.  So this is, in essence, doing a projection in $\Bbb R^n$ onto a $2$-dimensional linear subspace.

But there are no $n$-dimensional hyperplanes in this story when your points live in $\Bbb R^2$.

If you try to do quadratic (or higher) regression, then you are looking at $3$-dimensional (and higher) linear subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ given by the column spaces of matrices with more columns.

Comment: I understood "We find the least squares solution by projecting the vector $\mathbf y$ onto the column space (image) of $A$." But I didn't understand,"So this is, in essence, doing a projection in $\Bbb R^n$ onto a $2$-dimensional linear subspace." What is the $2$-dimensional linear subspace.

Comment: The column space of $A$ is the $2$-dimensional subspace. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks that makes sense. The problem is I can visualize the solution,that is, the line in $R^2$. And for each point, in $R^2$ it is easy to see the projection on the line and error incurred. But in $R^n$, I almost can't visualize what anything means(the projection obtained on $R^n$, the error vector). What does each axis of $R^n$ represent? A data point?

Comment: You're not projecting on the line in $\Bbb R^2$. You're looking at the vertical displacements from your data points to the line and minimizing the sum of their squares.

Comment: Can you please look at the question. I have edited it.

Comment: I do not have a good answer for what those vectors mean in $\Bbb R^n$. But the projection of $\mathbf y$ onto that subspace is given by specific values $\bar m$ and $\bar b$, and those are the values we use as the coefficients in our equation for the least-squares line.